# How to use API token to access SmartsheetGov by Smartsheet API Python

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am wondering if you could provide your solution on how to connect my agency's **SmartsheetGov** by using Smartsheet API with python. I have tried to connect to our agency's SmartsheetGov by Smartsheet API with Python. However all I got is the response of the invalid token (You could tell the message below) after revoking and creating new tokens.

I tried to follow the [instruction](https://www.smartsheet.com/content-center/best-practices/tips-tricks/api-getting-started) in the link below and got my API token value (‘FwCw……’) by the steps 1 and 2.

[image: Steps to get the API token]

[image: Result to get the API token]

Then, I installed the python SDK by the Smartsheet Python SDK. The python script below was used to connect our SmartsheetGov.

```
import os
import smartsheet
os.environ['SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN'] = "FwCw...."(The incomplete value of token here was for the security)
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet()
sheetID = 7012956985038964
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheetID)
print(sheet)
```

However, I got the error message below:

```
{"response": {"statusCode": 401, "reason": "Unauthorized", "content": {"errorCode": 1002, "message": "Your Access Token is invalid.", "refId": "367b8x"}}}
{"result": {"code": 1002, "errorCode": 1002, "message": "Your Access Token is invalid.", "name": "ApiError", "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem. ", "refId": "367b8x", "shouldRetry": false, "statusCode": 401}}
```

Comment: client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(api_base=smartsheet.__gov_base__)

Comment: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#working-with-smartsheetgovcom-accounts

Comment: Hello @Magaren, Thanks for your help! The syntax (client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(api_base=smartsheet.__gov_base__)) works like a charm!!

Comment: Hello Morgan, where can I  upvote you?

Answer (score 2):

```
client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(api_base=smartsheet.__gov_base__)
```

reference: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#working-with-smartsheetgovcom-accounts

Comment: FYI, for anyone looking for info about using the Smartsheet API with Smartsheet Gov in the future, the docs cover this topic here: https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/Smartsheet-Gov. There you'll find a link to instructions for how to use the API with Smartsheet Gov for the various SDKs (including, for example, the Python SDK: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#working-with-smartsheetgovcom-accounts).

Comment: nice...upvoted =)